# render component based on the id of user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

There are four entities in my application. Each entity has their own role. if the id of user is 1, the page should show entity1 component and if the id of user is 2, the page should show entity2. I could show this but could not pass props doing my way.

Here is what i have done

```
const userTypes = [
  { id: '1', val: <Entity1 /> },
  { id: '2', val: <Entity2 /> },
  { id: '3', val: <Entity3 /> },
  { id: '4', val: <Entity4 /> }
];

const renderComponent = props => {
  const component = userTypes.filter(x => x.id === props.user.id);
  if (component) {
    return component[0].val;
  } else {
    return <div>can't get route. unknown issue.</div>;
  }
};

export default renderComponent;
```

This way i cant pass props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
if (component) {
  const Component = component[0].val;
  return <Component />;
} else {
  return <div>can't get route. unknown issue.</div>;
}
```

Comment: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check your code at renderComponent.js:18.

Comment: @Serenity ah right - you should also rewrite the `userTypes` object to: `{ id: '1', val: Entity1 }, ...`